# Implementing iter for list in F#

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming

I am new to programming in functional languages. I am attempting to implement the F# iter for list. I think it should be similar to collect in list but not sure how to go around it. This is my attempted iter function for list in F#:

```
let rec iter func list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl -> func hd iter func tl;;
```

The error of compilation is: `Type mismatch. Expecting a 'a but given a ('b -> 'a -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e list) -> 'b list -> 'e list The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and '('b -> 'a -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e list) -> 'b list -> 'e list'`

I'm not knowledgeable in F# to understand this error. If anyone could have some advices to guide me to a right direction I would really appreciate it. 
Thanks
 `

Comment: Are you the same person who posted the two earlier questions here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835642/implementing-collect-for-list-in-f?  I would suggest you read the source for list.fs which has implementations of all of the std lib..

Comment: where do I go to read the source for list.fs?

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs

Comment: it only said 
`let iter f list = Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.iter f list` and I want to actually learn how to implement it...

Comment: So go and find where that function is defined.  The answer to your question is there if you look hard enough,

Comment: The problem is with the `func hd iter func tl` piece of code - can you explain what you're trying to do there?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `iter` is `('T -> unit) -> 'T list -> unit`, i.e. it is used only for the side effects of the function.

The main problem is that you're passing too many arguments to `func`

```
let rec iter func list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl -> func hd iter func tl;; 
                      ^   ^   ^    ^
                      1   2   3    4
```

Four of them, but `func` only takes one; `func`'s type should be `'T -> unit`.

Inserting a semicolon (for sequencing) right after `func hd`, and making sure the result for the empty list has type `unit`, should do the trick.

```
let rec iter func list =
    match list with
    | [] -> ()
    | hd::tl -> func hd;
                iter func tl;;
```